# While loop add class to first result

Tags: php

I have the following

```
while ( $query->have_posts() )
{
$query->the_post();
if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() )
{
    echo "<div class='clearfix card-prod ".($i==0?'first':'')."'><div class='top-dets'><span class='card-title'>";
    echo the_title();
    echo "</span>";


// Network query 
    $network_value = get_post_custom_values('srchnetwork');
    foreach ( $network_value as $key => $value ) {
    echo '<span class="srch-val-">'. $value . '</span>'; }

// Pricing Query
    $pricing_value = get_post_custom_values('srchpricing');
    foreach ( $pricing_value as $key => $value ) {
    echo '<span class="srch-val-1">'. $value . '</span>'; }

// Setup Query
    $setup_value = get_post_custom_values('srchsetupfee');
    foreach ( $setup_value as $key => $value ) {
    echo '<span class="srch-val-2">'. $value . '</span>'; }

// Services Query
    $services_value = get_post_custom_values('srchservices');
    foreach ( $services_value as $key => $value ) {
    echo '<span class="srch-val-3">'. $value . '</span></div>'; }

// Big Card Query
    $bigcard_value = get_post_custom_values('bigcard');
    foreach ( $bigcard_value as $key => $value ) {
    echo '<img src="wp-content/themes/cafc/images/cards/'. $value . '" />'; }


//      echo '<img src="wp-content/themes/cafc/images/top-choice.jpg" alt="Top Choice" class="topchoice">';

    echo the_excerpt()."</div>";   }};
}
```

Im wondering if its possible that I can wrap the first returned result within a span tag? if so how would I go about doing this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i = -1;
while ( $query->have_posts() )
{
$i++;
$query->the_post();
if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() )
{
echo "<div class='clearfix card-prod ".($i?'first':'')."'><div class='top-dets'><span class='card-title'>";
echo the_title();
echo "</span>";
...
```

Check this line `( $i ? 'first' : '')`.

Comment: When using the code on a FOR loop the 'first' gets placed on the second item, easy fix ( $i ? '' : 'first'). That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

As a general approach, any time you need behavior to only execute on the first time through a loop, you can simply use a flag variable to check whether to execute that behavior.

```
$firstLoop = true;
while( $query->have_posts() ){

    //do some things

    if( $firstLoop ){
        //do things on only the first loop
    }

    //do other things

    $firstLoop = false;
}
```

Or, for a foreach loop:

```
$firstLoop = true;
foreach( $network_value as $key => $value ){

    if( $firstLoop ){
        //do things on only the first loop
    }

    //do other things

    $firstLoop = false;
}
```

This avoids needing to count loops, and it works for any loop structure. Just remember to always set your flag variable to false at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can take help from a counter :

```
$count  = 0;
while(){
  <div class="<?php $count++; if($count == 1) { echo ' active'; } ?>">hello</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption on that basis would then result in something like this around each loop...

```
// Network query
$neti = 1;
$network_value = get_post_custom_values ( 'srchnetwork' );
foreach ( $network_value as $key => $value ) {
  if($neti == 1){
      echo '<span class="srch-val-">' . $value . '</span>';
  }else{
      echo $value;
  }
  $neti++;
}
```

Comment: @scottevans93, if you have questions for the original poster, it's better to ask them as comments on the question itself, rather than entering them as a possible answer.

Comment: @Jazz It would not let me for some strange reason.

Comment: @scottevans93 Do you have enough reputation to post comments (in places other than on your own answers) yet?